# Android - Supporting Multiple Screens

Tags: android, screen, screen-resolution

I have made a simple application, with a background image, 4 image buttons and 4 text views in front of them.

I've read the google development documentation, but I still don't understand why in screens with a different size of 4,7" the app doesn't run normally. The textview is not in the right place. The image buttons are too small or too big in wrong places

I've created different images for differente resolutions (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi,xhdpi).

Here is the xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gameinterface"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".QuestionsActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="137dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvQuestion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNumQuestion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#B22222"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/20"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#B22222"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="114dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnR1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector"
                android:src="@drawable/answerbutton" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvR1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnR3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector"
                android:src="@drawable/answerbutton" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvR3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnR2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector"
                android:src="@drawable/answerbutton" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvR2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnR4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector"
                android:src="@drawable/answerbutton" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvR4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the app doesn't run normally."?

Comment: if possible show some printscreens and explain what's wrong

Comment: instead of keeping different resolution images in different folder, create a folder called 'drawable' under 'res' folder and keep all the original images in it.

Comment: The textview are not in the right place. The image buttons are too small or too big in wrong places